# DocuSign Embedded RequestRecipientToken - 500 internal Server Error

Tags: vb.net, x509certificate, soap-client, x509, docusignapi

-Issue Resolved
On Live accounts that Use Embedded Signing, The Account Manager will need to either disable In Session or apply the accounts X.509 Certificate.

There is no way to bypass without the DocuSign Account Managers/Customer Support making updates to non forward facing settings.

-Using SOAP API in a VB.NET application.

I have recently moved our application to live after endless testing on the staging environment. Everything is working as expected except when I get too opening the recipient signature page.

When I make the RequestRecipientToken call I receive the error "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."

The API log give me 00_Internal Server Error_RequestRecipientToken.txt

the log doesn't really give me any info just shows that call.

I know this all works on staging, and I have tried to have all my account settings the same on both environments.

After looking all over I saw that X509 Certificate was recommended, so I added this last line in my DSAPI 
-update code:

```
Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(uri As Uri) As WebRequest
    IntegratorKey = SettingsHelper.sIntegrationKey
    Password = SettingsHelper.sAPIPassword
    Username = SettingsHelper.sAPIUserName
    Dim r As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = MyBase.GetWebRequest(uri)
    r.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" & Username & "</Username><Password>" & Password & "</Password><IntegratorKey>" & IntegratorKey & "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>")

    Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
    Dim certs As X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, <{OUR VALUE}>, False)
    Dim cert As New X509Certificate2

    If certs.Count > 0 Then
        cert = certs(0)
        Dim securityToken = New X509SecurityToken(cert)
        r.ClientCertificates.Add(securityToken.Certificate)
    End If

    store.Close()
    Return r
End Function
```

This did not help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try again?